# Convert specific json elements to number in json

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following json object:

```
[{
    "WEIGHTED_ARR_LAST_SLP": "0.03801186624130076",
    "SLIPPAGE_INTERVAL_VWAP_BPS": "10.2711",
    "ROOT_ORDER_ID": "735422197553491",
    "ARRIVAL_MID_PX": "93.6100",
    "WEIGHTED_ARR_SLP": "0.12323190317127024",
    "AVG_PX": "93.6586",
    "LEAVES_QTY": "0",
    "WEIGHT": "0.02372627566400397",
    "PARTICIPATION_RATE": "0E-12",
    "LOCAL_REF_END_TIME": "2016-09-06 06:00:27.775",
    "WEIGHTED_IVWAP_SLP": "0.2436949499725512",
    "NOTIONAL_USD": "477940",
    "LIQ_CONSUMPTION": "15.21",
    "EXEC_QTY": "5103",
    "CL_ORD_ID": "7245294057012908344",
    "LOCAL_REF_START_TIME": "2016-09-06 05:59:57.844",
    "SLIPPAGE_END_LAST_ARR_LAST_BPS": "1.6021",
    "IVWAP_PX": "93.5625",
    "LIMIT_PX": "93.6100",
    "ORDER_ID": "735422197553491",
    "SLIPPAGE_ARR_MID_BPS": "5.1939",
    "ORDER_QTY": "5103",
    "EXECUTION_STYLE": "2", {"ORDER_QTY": "5100", ..........}
}]
```

I want to coonvert only "`Ord Qty", "Exec Qty", "AVG Px", "Notional", "Limit Px", "Arrival Px" "Arrival Px Slpg", "IVWAP Px Slpg", "LIQ Consumption"` to Number; and then display `WEIGHTED_IVWAP_SLP` & `WEIGHTED_ARR_SLP` with 4 decimal points, instead of so many. I'm trying to do it in the following way:

```
var jsondata = document.getElementById("jsonArray").value;
var jsondataObj = JSON.parse(jsondata);

function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

var parsedData = jsondataObj.map(function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(memo, key) {
        var value = obj[key];
        //console.log(value);
        memo[key] = isNumeric(value) ? Number(value).toFixed(4) : value;
        //localStorage.setItem("storeditem", value);

        return memo;
    }, {})
});
```

But this is converting all of fields of numbers with 4 decimal point. How to convert only specific fields?

Comment: Create an array with the index names you want to convert to 4 decimals and when looping check if the key you are at is inside that array, you convert. Else you continue

Comment: This isn't a JSON question, just that your code start with decoding a JSON string doesn't make it about JSON. You just have some data structure in Javascript.

Comment: Yeah it's technically just a JavaScript a logic question, not a JSON question.  I'll suggest an edit to remove the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a practical example:

```
var x = {
    a: '1.11111',
  b: '2.22222',
  c: '3.33333',
  d: '4.444444',
  e: '5.55555'
}

var y = ['a', 'd'];

for(key in x) {
    if(y.indexOf(key) != -1) {
    x[key] = Number(x[key]).toFixed(2);
  }
}

console.log(x);
```

X is your object and Y is an array containing the list of keys you want to convert to fixed, or whatever you want to do.
When going through the keys, if the key is inside that array, you do your thing.

https://jsfiddle.net/dtuLxzy6/

Comment: This isn't working for me. It is still showing the long decimal numbers instead of just 4 points. FYI, I have a array

Comment: You have an array and inside that you have an object. My example started from the object. You can easily modify it to meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of doing your job for you right? Well, this answer doesn't use your code, but you should be able to apply it just the same. This uses language constructs such as [**`if`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else), [**`for`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and [**`for ... in`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) as opposed to methods of [**`Array`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) like [**`map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [**`reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and [**`filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var a = [{
  "WEIGHTED_ARR_LAST_SLP": "0.03801186624130076",
  "SLIPPAGE_INTERVAL_VWAP_BPS": "10.2711",
  "ROOT_ORDER_ID": "735422197553491",
  "ARRIVAL_MID_PX": "93.6100",
  "WEIGHTED_ARR_SLP": "0.12323190317127024",
  "AVG_PX": "93.6586",
  "LEAVES_QTY": "0",
  "WEIGHT": "0.02372627566400397",
  "PARTICIPATION_RATE": "0E-12",
  "LOCAL_REF_END_TIME": "2016-09-06 06:00:27.775",
  "WEIGHTED_IVWAP_SLP": "0.2436949499725512",
  "NOTIONAL_USD": "477940",
  "LIQ_CONSUMPTION": "15.21",
  "EXEC_QTY": "5103",
  "CL_ORD_ID": "7245294057012908344",
  "LOCAL_REF_START_TIME": "2016-09-06 05:59:57.844",
  "SLIPPAGE_END_LAST_ARR_LAST_BPS": "1.6021",
  "IVWAP_PX": "93.5625",
  "LIMIT_PX": "93.6100",
  "ORDER_ID": "735422197553491",
  "SLIPPAGE_ARR_MID_BPS": "5.1939",
  "ORDER_QTY": "5103",
  "EXECUTION_STYLE": "2"
}];
var fieldsToConvertToNumbers = [
  "ORDER_QTY", "EXEC_QTY", "AVG_PX",
  "NOTIONAL_USD", "LIMIT_PX", "ARRIVAL_MID_PX",
  "WEIGHTED_IVWAP_SLP", "LIQ_CONSUMPTION"
];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
  var b = a[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < fieldsToConvertToNumbers.length; ++j) {
    var field = fieldsToConvertToNumbers[j];
    if (field in b) {
      var value = parseFloat(b[field]);
      if (!isNaN(value))
        b[field] = value;
    }
  }
}
var pre = document.createElement("pre");
pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(a, null, ' ')));
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

Use [**`parseFloat`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to convert the values to numbers, but be sure to check for [**`NaN`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) results before deciding to update the value. Use [**`IsNaN`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) for that. Don't think you really need to use **`!`**[**`IsFinite`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite), but knock yourself out.

So now you want to use [**`toFixed`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to fix your string display.

```js
var text = (3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971).toFixed(4);
var pre = document.createElement("pre");
pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

So now you can use [**`toFixed`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to convert your numbers to strings that have only 4 decimal places of precision. However, they are strings instead of numbers. So you have to parse them back using [**`parseFloat`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

```js
var a = [{
  "WEIGHTED_ARR_LAST_SLP": "0.03801186624130076",
  "SLIPPAGE_INTERVAL_VWAP_BPS": "10.2711",
  "ROOT_ORDER_ID": "735422197553491",
  "ARRIVAL_MID_PX": "93.6100",
  "WEIGHTED_ARR_SLP": "0.12323190317127024",
  "AVG_PX": "93.6586",
  "LEAVES_QTY": "0",
  "WEIGHT": "0.02372627566400397",
  "PARTICIPATION_RATE": "0E-12",
  "LOCAL_REF_END_TIME": "2016-09-06 06:00:27.775",
  "WEIGHTED_IVWAP_SLP": "0.2436949499725512",
  "NOTIONAL_USD": "477940",
  "LIQ_CONSUMPTION": "15.21",
  "EXEC_QTY": "5103",
  "CL_ORD_ID": "7245294057012908344",
  "LOCAL_REF_START_TIME": "2016-09-06 05:59:57.844",
  "SLIPPAGE_END_LAST_ARR_LAST_BPS": "1.6021",
  "IVWAP_PX": "93.5625",
  "LIMIT_PX": "93.6100",
  "ORDER_ID": "735422197553491",
  "SLIPPAGE_ARR_MID_BPS": "5.1939",
  "ORDER_QTY": "5103",
  "EXECUTION_STYLE": "2"
}];
var fieldsToConvertToNumbers = [
  "ORDER_QTY", "EXEC_QTY", "AVG_PX",
  "NOTIONAL_USD", "LIMIT_PX", "ARRIVAL_MID_PX",
  "LIQ_CONSUMPTION"
];
var fieldsToConvertToFixedNumbers = [
  "WEIGHTED_IVWAP_SLP", "WEIGHTED_ARR_SLP"
];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
  var b = a[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < fieldsToConvertToNumbers.length; ++j) {
    var field = fieldsToConvertToNumbers[j];
    if (field in b) {
      var value = parseFloat(b[field]);
      if (!isNaN(value))
        b[field] = value;
    }
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < fieldsToConvertToFixedNumbers.length; ++j) {
    var field = fieldsToConvertToFixedNumbers[j];
    if (field in b) {
      var value = parseFloat(b[field]);
      if (!isNaN(value))
        b[field] = parseFloat(value.toFixed(4));
    }
  }
}
var pre = document.createElement("pre");
pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(a, null, ' ')));
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

So now only the specific fields have 4 decimal places. And they're numbers, not strings.

Comment: Fixed missing quote.

Comment: Finished revising.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your code slightly by adding a filter on the keys, before launching the `reduce()`. Secondly, you could put an extra condition in your ternary operator, to deal with the two fields that should get 4 decimal digits:

```
var parsedData = jsondataObj.map(function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).filter (
        key => ["ORDER_QTY", "EXEC_QTY", "AVG_PX", "NOTIONAL_USD", "LIMIT_PX", 
                "ARRIVAL_MID_PX", "WEIGHTED_ARR_SLP", "WEIGHTED_IVWAP_SLP", 
                "LIQ_CONSUMPTION"].includes(key)
    ).reduce(function(memo, key) {
        var value = obj[key];
        memo[key] = !isNumeric(value) ? value
             : ["WEIGHTED_IVWAP_SLP", "WEIGHTED_ARR_SLP"].includes(key) 
                 ? Number(value).toFixed(4) 
                 : Number(value);
        return memo;
    }, Object.assign({}, obj))
});
```

Note that you must then also pass a copy of the original object as initial value for `reduce`. For this `Object.assign` can be used.

Also, be aware that `.toFixed` turns a number back to string type, as this is the only way to actually ensure you see 4 decimal digits. If you want to really have the number type, then apply `Number()` to that result again:

```
Number(Number(value).toFixed(4))
```

Of course, trailing decimal zeroes will not display when you output such numbers without formatting.

```js
var jsondata = `[{
    "WEIGHTED_ARR_LAST_SLP": "0.03801186624130076",
    "SLIPPAGE_INTERVAL_VWAP_BPS": "10.2711",
    "ROOT_ORDER_ID": "735422197553491",
    "ARRIVAL_MID_PX": "93.6100",
    "WEIGHTED_ARR_SLP": "0.12323190317127024",
    "AVG_PX": "93.6586",
    "LEAVES_QTY": "0",
    "WEIGHT": "0.02372627566400397",
    "PARTICIPATION_RATE": "0E-12",
    "LOCAL_REF_END_TIME": "2016-09-06 06:00:27.775",
    "WEIGHTED_IVWAP_SLP": "0.2436949499725512",
    "NOTIONAL_USD": "477940",
    "LIQ_CONSUMPTION": "15.21",
    "EXEC_QTY": "5103",
    "CL_ORD_ID": "7245294057012908344",
    "LOCAL_REF_START_TIME": "2016-09-06 05:59:57.844",
    "SLIPPAGE_END_LAST_ARR_LAST_BPS": "1.6021",
    "IVWAP_PX": "93.5625",
    "LIMIT_PX": "93.6100",
    "ORDER_ID": "735422197553491",
    "SLIPPAGE_ARR_MID_BPS": "5.1939",
    "ORDER_QTY": "5103",
    "EXECUTION_STYLE": "2"
}]`;

var jsondataObj = JSON.parse(jsondata);

function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

var parsedData = jsondataObj.map(function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).filter (
        key => ["ORDER_QTY", "EXEC_QTY", "AVG_PX", "NOTIONAL_USD", "LIMIT_PX", 
                "ARRIVAL_MID_PX", "WEIGHTED_ARR_SLP", "WEIGHTED_IVWAP_SLP", 
                "LIQ_CONSUMPTION"].includes(key)
    ).reduce(function(memo, key) {
        var value = obj[key];
        memo[key] = !isNumeric(value) ? value
             : ["WEIGHTED_IVWAP_SLP", "WEIGHTED_ARR_SLP"].includes(key) 
                 ? Number(value).toFixed(4) 
                 : Number(value);
        return memo;
    }, Object.assign({}, obj))
});

console.log(parsedData);
```

Comment: Yeah that's a good simple solution. Be sure to note his field names are wrong. :)

Comment: @TylerY86, thanks for highlighting the wrong field names in the question. Corrected.

Comment: I missed it first, but he wants specific fields to have 4 digits, and the rest to just be numbers. Also, not strings?

Comment: You're right, @TylerY86, there is a two-level task here. I missed it too.

Comment: I wanted to make him work for it a bit more than adding to his code; if he doesn't understand that an array, a for loop and an if statement can solve the problem, maybe he shouldn't be using filter yet. lol ... I think your answer will be the most succinct correct answer here.